# Sensor effectivenes during reentry

Tags: science-based, warfare, space, shipbuilding

What sensors and communication systems would function as intended on a military vehicle during reentry into Earth's atmosphere? (And passing through thermosphere, ionosphere, stratosphere... etc, experiencing heat)

My question is about radars, hyperspectral cameras, laser rangefinders... etc., but not about Star Trek style handwavium scanners, and not about barometers (since they provide navigationally, but not tactically useful data (can not spot and identify threats))

Edit: We are talking about relatively near future technology. I made serious mistake previously since I'm asking about radars, hyperspectral cameras, laser rangefinders... etc. And other possible senors, which can be useful to detect other objects (eg. incoming missiles) and enemy EM activity, since we are discussing a military spacecraft doing the reentry. Fast and slow entry are both options to consider.

Comment: How far in the future? And what type of reentry? Slow one? Or the one we use now, with a lot of compression heat? And why would you need sensors then? What's the use?

Comment: @Mołot I preferred your original comment, I got happy from thinking that NASA uses a lot of compassion when they bring stuff back to earth :)

Comment: @Mrkvička writing from a phone. Easy to get bad auto-correction, and easy to swipe on enter my accident.  But yea. Compassion heat sounds good :D

Comment: Are you trying to live stream on YouTube in that situation? It's difficult but not impossible because you need durable fire/shock-resistance antenna scrapped tightly around ur Faraday cage...

Comment: I edited to clarify the question. Close voters would you care to share reasons you think this question is unclear?

Comment: If you have a powerful enough transmitter, you can maintain an outbound radio link (inbound could be more difficult), the same goes for lasers, a powerful enough beam can get *out* but all the turbulent plasma will make the much weaker returning signal about as coherent as a book that's just gone through a blender...

Comment: china got antiship ballistic missile right now that does what you say. how it works is a secret thou

Answer (score 2):

I think the ram-pressure fireball will block any reasonable optical or radio communication.

What you can do is relay the signal from a station above and behind the capsule, so it comes from a direction opposite the fireball.  The capsule provides a shadow, and the detector can be highly directional.

Answer (score 0):

JDługosz's [answer](/a/67379/43697) hints at this but doesn't really explain.

The plasma shockwave that forms in front of a vehicle *rapidly* entering the atmosphere is likely to cause two issues with sensors and/or communications. First, anything you point too directly in that direction needs to be able to withstand the heat. Second, it's hard for EM to penetrate.

This is why Apollo lost comms during reentry.

**The space shuttle didn't have this problem.**

...which is to say, it "did" — physics hasn't changed, of course — but the problem is *very directional*. All that nasty plasma is only on *one* side of your reentry vehicle. Apollo had little to nothing in the way of orbital infrastructure, but these days we have the [TDRSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System) that allows a reentering vehicle to relay off of assets that are *above* it.

The answer to your question is going to depend on  what assets you have *besides* the reentry vehicle. A "mothership" remaining in orbit may be sufficient all on its own to relay comms and whatever sensors you need. Well established infrastructure *certainly* ought to suffice... it's not even "near future" tech, it's tech that *already exists* for some decades. OTOH, if you're trying for a "stealth" (or at least "limited warning", since entry fireballs are about as *un*-stealthy as you can get) insertion on a planet you don't control, you might be SOL.